# Ionic - change build target directory

Tags: ionic-framework

I have a mobile app project using Angular and Ionic; there is a new requirement to produce two versions of the app that differ only in the assets loaded (including i18n localization files). Also, for the iOS app, the icons and app identifier need to be different.
In short, I would like to set up the iOS build command to target a different directory depending on the app. Currently `ionic cap sync` syncs to the default directory `ios` which would mean each time I had to build the alternate version of the app I would have to go into Xcode and change the icons etc.
How do I set the target directory to be unique for each version of the app?

Answer (score 0):

In your `capacitor.config` file you can set the output path for the ios build.

eg:

```
const config: CapacitorConfig = {
  ...
  ios: {
    path: 'my-custom-path'
  }
}
```

You can check the documentation [here](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/config)